# ClickOnce: публикация дополнительных файлов вместе с приложением

Tags: clickonce

Проект выгружает данные по шаблону в Excel. Для этого в папке программы есть файл \Templates\Шаблон.xmlx. На этапе разработки все работает, т.к. этот файл содержится в нужной папке.

После публикации приложения (ClickOnce), этого фала нет, он не опубликовывается с программой. Как его опубликовывать приложением с включением этих файлов? И где потом его искать (я имею ввиду в программе)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того  что-бы файл попал в публикацию необходимо выполнить следующие действия:

1. Выберите файл в обозревателе решений.
2. В окне "**Свойства**" измените значение свойства **Действие при сборке** на **Содержимое**.

Справка от Microsoft: [Задание файлов, публикуемых с помощью ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kzy0fky2.aspx)